# Detect text only inside detected objects

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

I'm very new to Computer Vision, I'm tryind to build a CV model which will detect and recognize price tags and extract info from it. I've already trained model that can detect price tags using YOLO. But I also want to teach my system to detect and recognize text which only written inside these price tags. Than parse this info into different parts, for example: price, product name, product description. Or mayby I firstly need to parse detected blocks (price block on the left side of the price tag, product name on the right side, etc.) then read it. Any ideas would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first one that pops into my mind would be to crop the objects detected with YOLO and then run the OCR on that image. After running OCR, you'll have to do some postprocessing to classify each line of text to a specific category (price, name etc.)

Comment: I think, it definitely makes sence